# d3.v4 bar graph using d3.tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Currently d3 Bar Graph value is working but its triggered with mouse hover:

```
 g.append('g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + x0(d.State) + ',0)')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(d => keys.map(key => {return {key: key, value: d[key]}}))
    .enter().append('rect')
     .attr('x', d => x1(d.key))
     .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
     .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
     .attr('height', d => innerHeight - y(d.value))
     .attr('fill', d =>  z(d.key))
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

Here's the code using d3.tip

```
const tip = d3.tip()
 .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {

   return "<strong><b style='color:#a9a9a9;font-size:18px;'>"+d.key+"</b>:</strong> <span class="+ GColor(d.key) +" style=font-size:16px; border: 1px solid green; padding: 0 20px 0 0 ><br><br>" + d.value + "</span>";
                      })
```

This code is working using `mouse hover` and d3.tip html displayed on top.

But the question is:
Is it possible to display `d.value` upon creating `.enter().append('rect')` right away of `rect` creation without `mouse hover` code?

iv'e tried some attempt but no luck replacing this code

```
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
```

something like `.append('text').Text(d.value)`

Any great idea is pretty much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to add labels to your bar chart? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491106/add-labels-to-bar-chart-d3

Comment: thanks @Anko yes i need the value which is displayed upon loading the graph. no need to use mouse hover